# Custom URL using Taxonomy and Custom User information (Real Name)

Tags: uri

Secondly, in the future I'm looking to organise Users by Taxonomy and having the url path relate to that:

/?q=***taxonomy-tag-here***/***user-fullname-here*** (not username, would be a custom field on the registration form).

How hard would this be to do, are there any modules that can do this, or would I have to create one?

I'm new to Drupal, but I've worked with Wordpress and Joomla a lot in the past and I'm looking to move onto Drupal, so please, be patronising when you explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to do quite simply with two modules [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) I guess. Token will propose you any field as token and you can use it into pathauto config to generate your urls.